# Work stealing mechanism of ForkJoinPool not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, forkjoinpool

I have the following test code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(2);

    ForkJoinTask task3 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        System.out.println("task 3 executing");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            System.out.println("task 3 doing work " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    ForkJoinTask task2 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("task 2 executing");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("task 2 finishing");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    });

    pool.submit(task2);

    ForkJoinTask task1 = pool.submit(() -> {
        System.out.println("task 1 executing");
        pool.submit(task3); // EDIT: Original code was task3.fork();
        System.out.println("task 1 joining task 2");
        task2.join();
        System.out.println("task 1 finished");
    });

    task1.join();
}
```

It basically submits 3 tasks to a ForkJoinPool of parallelism 2, task 2 and 3 are  long running and task 1 waits for task 2.

Labeling the 2 threads t1 and t2, where t1 executes task1 and t2 executes task2.

In my understanding, the work-stealing magic happens within the join() call, where the calling thread would execute a task from either its own work queue or other worker threads' work queue. Thus I'm expecting t1 to execute task1, sees the join() call then steal task3 and execute it to completion.

However, in practice, t1 does not do anything special with the join() call. Task3 is only executed after both task1 and task2 has finished. Why is this the case?

Comment: I don't see task3 submit in the above code

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I changed task3.fork() to pool.submit(task3). However it doesn't change the behavior I described

Comment: task1 will be the last to complete since it waits for task2 to finish which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: My question is why thread1 is not executing task3 while it is joining task2

Comment: how do you know which thread is executing the tasks? You only submit tasks to the pool, the pool manages the allocation to individual threads.

Comment: Right, that is why I created a pool of maximum 2 threads and labeled the threads t1 and t2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169542/discussion-between-shawn-li-and-nitnamby).

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours looking into the source code of ForkJoinPool and ForkJoinTask, here is what I've found:

join() will cause a thread to look and steal tasks, given one of the following two conditions are met:

1. The task being joined is located at the top of the current worker thread's work queue, in which case the worker thread will continue to execute that task (see below)
2. There is task from the work queue of another worker thread, but only if that worker thread has stolen a task from the current worker thread, then the current worker thread will steal back a task and execute it (see below)

For the first case, I deduced it primarily from the `doJoin()` method in ForkJoinTask.java and below is a working test that illustrates the case:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(2);

    ForkJoinTask task3 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        System.out.println("task 3 executing on thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            System.out.println("task 3 doing work " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    ForkJoinTask task2 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("task 2 executing on thread " + Thread.currentThread());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("task 2 finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    });

    ForkJoinTask task1 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        System.out.println("task 1 executing on thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        pool.submit(task3);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("task 1 joining task 3");
        task3.join();
        System.out.println("task 1 finished");
    });

    pool.submit(task2);
    pool.submit(task1);

    task1.join();
}
```

The output is

```
task 1 executing on thread Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
task 2 executing on thread Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
task 1 joining task 3
task 3 executing on thread Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
task 3 doing work 0
task 3 doing work 1
task 3 doing work 2
task 3 doing work 3
task 2 finished
task 3 doing work 4
task 3 doing work 5
task 3 doing work 6
task 3 doing work 7
task 3 doing work 8
task 3 doing work 9
task 1 finished
```

Task3 and task1 are executed on the same worker thread, which is expected since task3 is directly submitted to thread2's work queue and therefore according to case 1 it should be executed when task1 calls join() on it.

I deduced the second case based on the `awaitJoin()` method in ForkJoinPool.java, below is a working test that illustrates the case

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(2);

    ForkJoinTask task3 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        System.out.println("task 3 executing on thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            System.out.println("task 3 doing work " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    ForkJoinTask task2 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("task 2 executing on thread " + Thread.currentThread());
            pool.submit(task3);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("task 2 finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    });

    ForkJoinTask task1 = ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
        System.out.println("task 1 executing on thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        pool.submit(task2);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("task 1 joining task 2");
        task2.join();
        System.out.println("task 1 finished");
    });

    pool.submit(task1);

    task1.join();
    task2.join();
    task3.join();
}
```

and the output

```
task 1 executing on thread Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
task 2 executing on thread Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
task 1 joining task 2
task 3 executing on thread Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
task 3 doing work 0
task 3 doing work 1
task 3 doing work 2
task 3 doing work 3
task 2 finished
task 3 doing work 4
task 3 doing work 5
task 3 doing work 6
task 3 doing work 7
task 3 doing work 8
task 3 doing work 9
task 1 finished
```

Task3 executed on thread1 as task1 is waiting for task2, this is possible because task2 was submitted to thread1's work queue, but since thread2 is free, it stole the task can became a stealer for thread1. When thread1 sees the join() call from task1, it looks at the stealer (thread2)'s work queue and found task3, took it and execute it.

Also note that task1 finished executing only after task3, which means that once the thread has stolen a task, it must executes it to completion.

Now for the original question, I have submitted both task1 and task2 in a non-ForkJoinWorkerThread (the main thread), thus non of the worker thread steals from each other so the second case doesn't apply. Furthermore, since I called join() on the second task, which is in thread2's work queue, therefore the first case doesn't apply and thus no stealing happens.

Edit:
The is by no mean an answer to F/J in java, if there are any problems please point them out. In fact digging all these details out only created more problems: namely, why won't a worker thread just take an arbitrary task and run it? why must it come from a stealer or its own work queue? if you have the answer please do comment / post.

Comment: The fact that the fork join framework has unexpected behavior is enough for me to avoid it entirely. The minute I saw it allocate more threads than I prescribed, I let it go. And here, you are telling me it doesn't always steal predictably. I'm sure they have a reason, I just don't want to hear it. I would rather design a good event-driven system than grasping onto blocking threads ideology. The Fork Join framework is a lemon.

Comment: You are probably right. I just have a large burst of tasks to deal with so I need to use something better than raw threads

Comment: Then use executor services, see Executors.newFixedThreadPool() and move on. If you truly have dependant tasks, just use CompletableFutures.

Comment: In fact this is supposed to be for an Android project. I had to port back CompletableFuture because that is not supported for all API levels. In my implementation I would start a new thread for each task. I currently have tasks that dependent on each other, so I do need ForkJoinPool, only to find that it is not supported on all API level either, so I had to implement it as well.

Comment: I presume you have an executor service. Then it should be quite trivial to have your tasks post new tasks; for instance, if taskB depends on taskA, then taskA would submit taskB, and you avoid taskB needing to join taskA. Can you detail why you need .join()? I can guess you have a scatter-gather problem, but to me, it only means the last scatterred task to complete fires the gathering task. It's a simple atomicInteger.decrementAndGet()<=0.